# iOS: captureOutput function isn't called using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, capture, avcaptureoutput

I'm trying to implement a View which can show the preview video of the rear camera and process the captured frames. 
I would like to use two outputs: one to save the video and one to process each frame.

```
let movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
```

I have added the delegates to my view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
```

Also I have added my outputs to the AVCaptureSession:

```
do {
    videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable as! String: NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
    videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "videosamplequeue")
    videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    guard captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) else {
        fatalError()
    }
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput){
        captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
    }

    videoConnection = videoDataOutput.connection(withMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo)
}

if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
    captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
}
```

My preview layer works perfectly and I can see the picture display in my UI view. But captureOutput is never called. If I comment:

```
//if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
//        captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
//    }
```

then, my captureOutput is called and works fine, but I would like to save my video in a file.
I'm working with swift 3, so I'm using:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when you remove the other source, it's still calling `captureOutput` maybe with fake data, but still for videoDataOutput, because you set `sampleBufferDelegate` for it. But `captureOutput` isn't meant for `movieOutput`.

`movieOutput` is `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, which is a subclass of `AVCaptureFileOutput`.

`AVCaptureFileOutput` implements two protocols: [AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate and AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutput)

You should implement one of them (read the documentation to decide which one fits your requirement), and implement their methods, and expect them to be invoked, rather than `captureOutput` to be called twice.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling: videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue) and works, the problem is when I add the second output to the capture session: captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

Comment: There is one more delegate involved, see edited answer.

Comment: I'm getting "Value of type 'AVCaptureMovieFileOutput' has no member 'delegate'". This implementation works if I remove captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput). Each output works if I remove the other

Comment: Have  you tried doing this?  movieOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue) Do it along with videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue). Not one way or the other.

Comment: Yes, but movieOutput is AVCaptureMovieFileOutput and has no member called setSampleBufferDelegate

Comment: ok, so movieOutput is AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, which is a subclass of AVCaptureFileOutput. AVCaptureFileOutput has a delegate (AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate) and that has 2 methods called: fileOutputShouldProvideSampleAccurateRecordingStart and fileOutput - look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutputdelegate - so you expecting ´captureOutput´ to be called twice is probably wrong. When you remove the other, its still calling it maybe with fake data because you set sampleBufferDelegate. But captureOutput isn't meant for movieOutput.

Comment: the method you are looking for is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutputdelegate/1390096-fileoutput

Comment: It sounds good but I'm getting 'AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate' is unavailable.  I'm using swift 3